# Rightmost JButton must always be visible inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

I have a header panel (`JPanel`) with a set of icon button (1-to-many) and a single button (`JButton`) with a symbol. When I resize the panel, I want the button with the symbol to always be visible regardless of size of the panel. This means that the set of icon buttons should be made invisible if need be.

What is the right Layout for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the button in the `LINE_END` (or more accurately, for RHS specifically, `EAST`) constraint of a `BorderLayout`.